# Dockerized Django application not accessible on specified port

Tags: django, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Django application running inside a Docker container on my server. I am trying to access it via a specific port, but it's not working as expected. Here are the relevant details:

**Dockerfile** (CMD section):

```
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:9000"]
```

**Jenkins Pipeline** (part of the Jenkinsfile):

```
stage('Build and Deploy') {
    steps {
        script {
            // Build the Docker image
            sh 'docker build -t my-django-app -f Dockerfile .'

            // Stop and remove the existing container (if any)
            sh 'docker stop my-django-container || true'
            sh 'docker rm my-django-container || true'

            // Run the Docker container
            sh 'docker run -d --name my-django-container -p 9000:9000 my-django-app'
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, I've allowed port 9000 through the firewall using the following command:

```bash
sudo ufw allow 9000/tcp
```

My Jenkins server is publicly available at `ip:8080`, but when I try to access my Django application at `ip:9000`, it doesn't work. I'm relatively new to Docker, and any assistance in troubleshooting this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a `EXPOSE 9000` line in your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Yes, here is that part of my Dockerfile:

`
EXPOSE 9000
# Specify the command to run when the container starts
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:9000"]
`

Comment: It could be that port is already taken on your machine, if on linux i think it is a mail port, try changing the port to one that is definitely not in use and try again. To check on windows its `netstat -ano`

Comment: I checked the port using
```
 netstat -tuln | grep 9000

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN

```
The docker container is running